# Roles/responsibilities of FragmentActivities vs. Fragments

Tags: android

Say I have an application with two instances of FragmentActivity, FragActivityA and FragActivityB, and two ListFragments, FragA and FragB.

In portrait, FragActivityA presents FragA, and upon selection starts FragActivityB presenting FragB.

Should FragA implement OnItemClickListener for the ListView (some networking business is performed on press), or FragActivityA? Should FragA show a DialogFragment, or should there be a callback to FragActivityA to show it?

When in landscape, FragActivityA presents both FragA and FragB. Now, if the answers to the above are yes, FragActivityA needs to include most methods of FragActivityB, duplicating most of the code. If the answers are no, then FragA or FragB need to present and handle DialogFragments themselves.

I'm looking for a little guidance on where I should be writing most of my code (my gut feeling is inside the Fragments), but Fragments displaying DialogFragments seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say I have an application with two instances of FragmentActivity, FragActivityA and FragActivityB, and two ListFragments, FragA and FragB.

I have an application with two instances of FragmentActivity, FragActivityA and FragActivityB, and two ListFragments, FragA and FragB.

Oh, no, wait, you didn't literally mean for me to say that... :-)

> Should FragA implement OnItemClickListener for the ListView (some networking business is performed on press), or FragActivityA?

`FragA` should override `onListItemClick()`. What happens at that point depends a bit on the business logic involved. You indicate that "some networking business is performed on press", which sounds like you are sending a command to an `IntentService` or possibly spawning an `AsyncTask`. My current thinking is that those things would also be done by `FragA`, though I am not as confident about that, particularly since I don't know much about your app.

> Should FragA show a DialogFragment, or should there be a callback to FragActivityA to show it?

Ideally, neither. Design your UI to lock the user out of *pieces* of the activity, not the whole activity. IOW, minimize your use of dialogs.

Regardless, my general guidance is that the fragment handles all work that is limited to the scope of the fragment itself (and its underlying data model). Events that transcend multiple fragments should be rippled up to the activity, which would then be responsible for either passing the event to another existing fragment (if it's loaded by this activity) or by starting another activity. In MVC terms, your fragment is your controller, with the activity handling orchestration events between fragments (and, hence, between activities if needed).

> Now, if the answers to the above are yes, FragActivityA needs to include most methods of FragActivityB, duplicating most of the code.

It sounds like they should inherit from a common `AbstractFragActivity` that implements the common logic.

Comment: Many thanks. Definitely some things in there that I need to take away and consider.